# Silverlight: Determine number of items based on ListBox width

Tags: c#, silverlight, listbox

There is a horizontal `ListBox` (of Images) in my application. At application startup, I need to add  some Images to the `ListBox` so that it fills the window width (no scroll is allowed). These images serve as position marker thumbnails of a huge set of Images. 
The problem occurs when I use different monitors. In low resolution monitors, the thumbnails overflow the window width (scroll bars appear) and in high resolution monitors empty spaces appear at the end of the `ListBox`. 
What is the best way to solve this.

I can add more thumnails if the `ListBox` width can be determined.
Since teh `ListBox` width is set to `"Auto"`, I am not sure how get the actual rendered size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It exists in wpf, not sure about silverlight, try the `ActualWidth` property.